# EF/ CodeFirst Relationship mapping

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a situation where i have  classes `JobDescription`   and  `Image` . I want to establish the relation of one to zero or many. If JobDescription exists it may have collection of images or may not have any image at all. Same goes with Image and ImageSection. With my classes am i doing right?

```
public class JobDescription
        {
            public int JobDescriptionID { get; set; }

           // Other attributes and navigations


            public int? ImageID { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("ImageID")]
            public virtual List<Image> Image { get; set; }

         }

      public class Image
        {
            public int ImageID { get; set; }

            public string ImageName { get; set; }

            public int? ImageSectionID { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("ImageSectionID")]
            public virtual ImageSection ImageSection { get; set; }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key property belongs to the "one" side of the relationship, not to the "many" side. Your model classes should look like this:

```
public class JobDescription
{
    public int JobDescriptionID { get; set; }

    // Other attributes and navigations

    public virtual List<Image> Image { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public int? JobDescriptionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("JobDescriptionID")]
    public virtual JobDescription JobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And the same kind of relationship for `ImageSection`. If an image always *must* have a `JobDescription` the `JobDescriptionID` in `Image` must be of type `int`, not `int?`. In this example the `ForeignKey` attribute is not necessary because EF will recognize the FK property by naming conventions.

Comment: Why there is ForeignKey in Image? I thought the ForeignKey of Image would be on JobDescription side as one JobDescription may have many Images as you explained in first paragraph.

Comment: @aneal: In the first paragraph with "one" side I meant the side where the (one single) *reference* is (`Image.JobDescription`) and the "many" side where the *collection* is (`JobDescription.Images`). Think about how a one-to-many relationship is modeled in a relational database: If a `JobDescription` has many images the `Image` table must have a foreign key (`JobDescriptionID`) to `JobDescription`. All images of a particular JobDescription have the same foreign key value. The model above expresses this database relation.